# Making Full Width td Table on Small Screens With Pure CSS Rules

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know how I can make the `td` full width of `100%` on small device like less than 800 in  way that second `td` apperais under the fist one With Pure CSS Rules?

```
<table class="responsive">
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Jan 19 2016</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

I already tried this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td{width:100% !important;}
}
```

to make 100% width of each td but this is not doing the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a reset on `display`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td {
    display: block
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZKqLz

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table-row;`

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  td{
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Date</td>
       <td>Jan 19 2016</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```